# pandas DataFrame type cast

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to cast the type of a DataFrame using the function `astype` in the same way it is used in NumPy.

First in NumPy:

```
In [175]: x = np.rec.array([('a','1'),('b','2')],names='col1,col2')

In [176]: x
Out[176]: 
rec.array([('a', '1'), ('b', '2')], 
    dtype=[('col1', '|S1'), ('col2', '|S1')])

In [177]: dt=[('col1', '|S1'), ('col2', 'i8')]

In [178]: x.astype(dt)
Out[178]: 
rec.array([('a', 1), ('b', 2)], 
    dtype=[('col1', '|S1'), ('col2', '<i8')])
```

Then in pandas:

```
In [182]: y = DataFrame([('a','1'),('b','2')], columns=['col1','col2'])

In [183]: y
Out[183]: 
  col1 col2
0    a    1
1    b    2

In [184]: y.astype(dt)
Out[184]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
...
NotImplementedError: Not implemented for this type
```

I'm using pandas 0.7.3 and from the documentation on pandas 0.7.0 at http://pandas.sourceforge.net/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrame is not a structured array and thus doesn't function in the same way with respect to data types. There's no API equivalent (to my knowledge, at least) to the record array operation you show there.

Comment: Ok, so if I want to convert the types of the columns in a DataFrame, I convert them column by column?